# When a trigger requires you to sacrifice something, can you sacrifice said something using something else?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say [Glacial Chasm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlacial%20Chasm%5d) enters the battlefield under my control. The card states that when it comes into play I must sacrifice a land. Can I in response to its ETB ability sacrifice a land using say [Zuran Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZuran%20Orb%5d)? When Glacial Chasm entered, a land was sacrificed. Is this allowed, and more to the point: is Glacial Chasm's ETB requirement met in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Most instances<sup>*</sup> of "enter the battlefield" denote triggered abilities, so they go on the stack and you can respond on them before they resolve, e.g. by activating another ability which can be played at instant speed, such as Zuran Orb's.

However, the land you sacrifice for Zuran Orb (even if it's Glacial Chasm itself) does **not** count for Glacial Chasm's enter the battlefield ability. So you'll have to sacrifice another land (unless you don't have any).

<sup>*</sup><sub>: some cards have "As [card name] enters the battlefield"; those are replacement effects and don't go on the stack. Those never involve sacrifices, though.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. The only thing is... say if someone targeted a land with say stripmine to destroy it. Could I in response sac the land to, for the sake of continuity, zuran orb. I presume so, since u can sac in response to a creature being targeted by a spell. Stripmine being an activated ability and not a spell however... does it change?

Comment: Yes, you can sacrifice your land to Zuran Orb in response to Strip Mine. The difference here is that Strip Mine's ability destroying the land is the *effect* rather than the cost.