# Magic the Gathering: Annihilator and Ashnods Altar

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent attacks me with an Ulamog the Infinite Gyre and its annihilator 4 triggers on me. If I have an Ashnods Altar, will sacrificing creatures to the ashnods altar count towards the annihilator 4?

Comment: It's not quite an exact duplicate, but this is very similar to https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/35026/2537, https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/33274/2537, https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/27512/2537, https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/49126/2537. The short answer is no, if you are sacrificing something for the annihilator trigger, you are only sacrificing it for that, and not for anything else.